# Converting date to dd-mm-yyyy with AngularJS and ASP.NET

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-controller

I am getting following date while returning from angular code 1/1/0001 in controller. date is displayed in proper format like below

[image]

My filter, which is in **angularjs**

```
  myApp.filter("DateOfBirth", function () {
    var re = /\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//;
    return function (x) {
        var m = x.match(re);
        if (m)
            return new Date(m);
        else
            return null;

    };
});
```

My **controller**

```
public string Update_Data(Employee employee)
        {
            if(employee != null)
            {
                var employee_ = projectContext.Entry(employee);
                Employee employeeObject = projectContext.Employees.Where(x => x.Employee_ID == employee.Employee_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                employeeObject.First_Name = employee.First_Name;
                employeeObject.Last_Name = employee.Last_Name;
                employeeObject.Country_ID = employee.Country_ID;
                employeeObject.State_ID = employee.State_ID;
                employeeObject.City_ID = employee.City_ID;
                employeeObject.Email = employee.Email;
                employeeObject.Password = employee.Password;
                employeeObject.Mobile = employee.Mobile;
                employeeObject.DateOfBirth =Convert.ToDateTime( employee.DateOfBirth);
                employeeObject.Age = employee.Age;
                projectContext.SaveChanges();
                return "Data Updated";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Please Check!!";
            }
        }
```

**angularjs** script

```
$scope.UpdateEmployee = function (Employee) {
        document.getElementById("EmployeeID_").value = Employee.Employee_ID;
        $scope.FirstName = Employee.First_Name;
        $scope.LastName = Employee.Last_Name;
        $scope.counter = Employee.Country_ID;
        $scope.Counter = Employee.State_ID;
        $scope.CityID = Employee.City_ID;
        $scope.Email = Employee.Email;
        $scope.Password = Employee.Password;
        $scope.DateOfBirth = Employee.DateOfBirth;
        $scope.Mobile = Employee.Mobile;
        $scope.Age = Employee.Age;
        document.getElementById("btnSave").setAttribute("value", "Update");
        document.getElementById("btnSave").style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        document.getElementById("spn").innerHTML = "Update Employee Information";
    };
```

I m getting this value in controller of **mvc** is

Comment: what is the value in `employee.DateOfBirth` without converting?

Comment: it is in this format /Date(733689000000)/.. I have used filters in angularjs to convert it into the dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: new Date(parseInt('/Date(733689000000)/'.substr(6))); try this

Comment: i have tried this but not working for me

Comment: @Kasturi any specific error you see. looks fine for me .

Comment: myApp.filter("DateOfBirth", function () {
    var re = /\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//;
    return function (x) {
        var m = x.match(re);
        if (m)
            return new Date(m);
        else
            return null;

    };
});

Comment: i am using this above filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Take a look at [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date) in particular [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date/2091162#2091162) for the better way to fix this

Comment: @Kasturi `if (m)` is always evaluating to false so it set's dateTime to null . so if you do convert.ToDateTime(null) you get `01.01.0001 00:00:00`

Comment: @supercool then what is correct solution for it

Comment: @Kasturi does it resolve the issue ?

Comment: @supercool noooo

Comment: I see it’s working check below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply look for `/Date` in the string and convert it, no need to over complicate things.

**code:**

```
app.filter('formatDate', function() {
   return function(item) {
     if (item.indexOf('/Date') != -1) 
     return new Date(parseInt(item.substr(6)));
     return item;
   };
});
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/h2uh5jpy/)**

I prefer to move this `new Date(parseInt(item.substr(6)));` logic to a service so it be injectable/reusable when needed to a filter/controller.